# What is the difference between spectral clustering and kernel spectral clustering?

Tags: clustering, kernel-trick, spectral-analysis

I have been reading about spectral clustering (SC) technique. So far I understood that it is based on computing the similarity between datapoints (using some function like the gausian kernel function) and then building the Lagrangian of this similarity matrix, and using the eigenvectors of the lagrangian to build the clusters.

This technique is therefore based pretty much on graph theory, but I have also read that it is connected to kernel k-means and specially with kernel PCA.

I have recently seen that there is another technique called kernel spectral clustering. I haven't found too much information about this KSC technique, actually the only thing I found is a book in which this technique is described as a *weighted kernel PCA* but I was actually unable to understand the way KSC is working, and therefore, how it is different from normal SC. Moreover, taking into account that as I said, the SC algorithm can be seem in terms of a kernel PCA problem, which seems to be the base of the KSC.

I would appreciate any explanation, or any book or paper I can be pointed to.

Comment: It's probably spectral clustering with a kernel function as similarity. Doesn't sound too different though. Is it published on any major conference/journal or low quality?

Comment: I found it published on a book titled "unsupervised learning" in which KSC has a full chapter. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00477. This is the url to a pdf version of that chapter, in which author starts making some sort of comparison between spectral clustering and kernel spectral clustering.